# How to decompress zlib

Tags: java, zlib

I am hoping to decompress a zlib file. 
Below is a picture of my original:

[image]

When byte no 4 is not equal to 0, it needs to decompress after 9th bytes.
After I decompress, I receive the following error:

```
"java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check"
```

My code is below:

```
private static void writeToRawInFile(byte[] bData) {
    try {
        int index = 4;
        byteBuffer = null;
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bData.length);

        byteBuffer.put(bData);
        byteBuffer.flip();
        byte[] convertByte = byteBuffer.array();
        System.out.println("Byte:" + convertByte.toString());
        if (byteBuffer.get(index) == 0) {
            System.out.println("index 0");
            byteBuffer = null;
            byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bData.length);

            byteBuffer.put(bData);
            byteBuffer.flip();
            //factoryType.fileServer.fc.write(byteBuffer);
        } else {
            //bData = Arrays.copyOfRange(bData, 1,9);
            bData = decompressByteArray(Arrays.copyOfRange(bData, 0,9));
            byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bData.length);
            byteBuffer.put(bData);
            byteBuffer.flip();
            System.out.println("data ="+ byteBuffer);
            //factoryType.fileServer.fc.write(byteBuffer);
        }

        //factoryType.fileServer.fc.write(byteBuffer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("expMsg .writeToRawInFile()=" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (byteBuffer != null) {
        byteBuffer.clear();
    }
}

public static byte[] decompressByteArray(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    System.out.println("Original: " + bytes.length);
    inflater.setInput(bytes);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while (!inflater.finished()) {
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    outputStream.close();

    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    System.out.println("Compressed: " + output.length);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean with `position 4` the (zero-based) `index 4`? If you need to decompress everything after index 9 this is wrong `Arrays.copyOfRange(bData, 0,9)` check [Arrays.copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-).

Comment: I just get result of Arrays.copyOf Range.  I mean is When the fourth bytes others then 0, need to do decompress.. the fourth bytes is compression flag, if the 4th bytes detect 0, it already uncompress, but if it detect else than 0, it need uncopress just first.

Comment: Maybe the bytes in range `0-8` are not zlib compressed. What are those bytes. Could you share an example?

Comment: u r correct..0-8 not zlib compressed.. after bytes 9 is zlib... The file will saying if the bytes range in 4th is 0, then will be skip, others values in the 4 th bytes will be do uncompress after bytes 9.

Comment: why are you converting the data to ByteBuffer only to check the value of the 4th (**index = 3!!**) byte? Just check `bData[3]`. And please CHECK your indexes - apparently the flag is the 4th byte, index=3; and the compressed data starts at the 10th byte, index=9 (assuming no line termination or other byte after the "H" in your picture... Using your counting, that is 4th byte is "1", the 9th byte is "4", probably not the compressed data.

Comment: But you try to decompress the bytes of index range `0-8`.

Comment: @SubOptimal What coding i should doing? Sorry, i'm new in Java programming.. I try many way, but still can't get the answer

Comment: First you need to sort out what kind of structure your input data has. Then figure out how to handle the separate parts independently. Create a proof of concept which deals with a byte array which is known to contain valid zlib compressed data (`78 9c 4b cb cf 4f 4a 2c 02 00 08 ab 02 7a`). When you have the small pieces working then you can start to combine them into something bigger.